# MySql performance is not realtime if number of records in a table is huge

Tags: mysql

If i am trying to populate a MySQL tabel with 1-5 million of records and trying to fetch 100 to 500 record out of it, then it is taking almost 1 sec.

Performance latency is increasing with increasing number of records in table and increasing read concurrency.

As i want realtime implementation so i am looking a letency not more then 150 ms.

Can this real time performance(150 ms latency with large dataset) be achieved via MySQL?

```
Table Schema -
CREATE TABLE ContactsAgentContacts(
       uniqueid integer not null,
       did varchar(32) not null,
       nId varchar(50),
       companyname varchar(50),
primary key (uniqueid,did)
)
```

Storage Engine - ndb

Sample query for read-

```
SELECT DISTINCT ContactsAgentContacts.companyname AS 'fullname' from ContactsAgentContacts where did='xyz';
```

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your database schema, but you haven't told us anything about it, so it's impossible for us to give you any useful advice.

Comment: Can you show the table layout? Did you specify a primary key/indexed column? What storage engine is the table using?

Comment: table layout and possible indexes?

Comment: @duskwuff - i added required information.

Comment: @ray- i added required information.

Comment: @RyanGadsdon Gadsdon- table layout added and primary key mentioned.

Comment: You are not using any index so you are doing a full table scan on that query. Add an index to "did" and it will be faster.

Comment: @Andreas Wederbrand did is already a part of composit primary key so primary index is already applied on did.

Comment: MySQL perforrmance is not 'real time' **at all.** It can't be, unless it is a real-time application running with real-time constraints, which it satisfies, under a real-time operating system.

Comment: @prashantsindhu it doesn't help that 'did' is a part of the primary key if the first parts (uniqueid) isn't a part of the query. Try with explain and you'll see.

Comment: Thanks,Got the point, with proper secondary indexing performance is up to mark.

Answer (score 0):

After proper secondary indexing(secondary index on did) performance is upto mark.(<50 ms).